# WPF ListView Column width

Tags: wpf

I used list view with a single column, I would like this column with the same size list view with. 
I mean Just one column fill the all with of the list view.

I tried this but didn't work...

```
        <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="LvErrorList">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>                    
                <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=LvErrorList}" Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ErrorMessage}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

I tried

```
 <GridViewColumn Width="Auto" Header="Status" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ErrorMessage}" />
```

But some text are longer than the with of the ListView. 
Becaues i don't know the user screen size i can't set max-width property.

Does anyone know how to fix this please?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way instead.

```
 <ListView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="LvErrorList">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn   Header="Status" >
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ErrorMessage}" Width="{Binding ElementName=LvErrorList,Path=ActualWidth}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```